# Excel Table into Organized Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel worksheet with data stored in the following way.

[image]

I would like to organize this data into a Pandas dataframe so that it looks like the following...

[image]

Having the data formatted like this will allow me to easily work with pivot tables and carry out analysis.

If there is an easy way to do this in excel as well, please let me know. Python would be the better choice, since I have hundreds of tables like this each with hundreds of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would tackle the problem with Python, though there may be a more elegant solution.

First I would parse the Month/Year values using openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('data_so.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']

year = str(sheet_ranges['A1'].value)
month = str(sheet_ranges['B1'].value)
```

From there I find the pandas package extremely useful for the types of manipulations you require, Setting multi-indices allow for easy reshaping (through stack).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('data_so.xlsx', skiprows=3)

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'Price'), ('A', 'Quantity'),
                                     ('B', 'Price'), ('B', 'Quantity'),
                                     ('C', 'Price'), ('C', 'Quantity')],
                                    names=['letters', 'index'])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.ix[:,:2].values.T,names=('Item', 'Code')) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.ix[:,2:].values, columns=columns, index=index)
df3 = df2.stack('letters').reset_index()
```

We can then set month and year to the values we collected:

```
df3['Year'] = year
df3['Month'] = month
```

[image: Output d3]

You can further call MultiIndex and stack to arrange Price and Quantity to what you want.  This isn't exactly clean but it solves your issue.

```
df3.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df3[['Item','Code','letters','Year','Month']].values.T,
                                      names=('Item', 'Code','letters','Year','Month'))
df4 = df3[['Price','Quantity']].stack()
df5 = pd.DataFrame(df4)
df5.columns = ['Value']
df5.reset_index()
```

[image: df5 ouput]